# Добавить строки из второй таблицы в первую без повторов

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть одна таблица, нужно к ней добавить значения из другой, но без повторов. Первое что приходит на ум

```
insert into <Таблица_1> 
    select * from <Таблица_2> 
        EXCEPT select * from <Таблица_1>
```

Выглядит громоздко. Есть ли более разумный способ?

Comment: а где именно тут громоздко?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MERGE <Таблица_1> AS T1
USING <Таблица_2> AS T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(ID, ...) VALUES(T2.ID, ...);
```